# Does the equation converges uniformly on open disk D(0, 1/3)

Tags: complex-analysis

Does the function converges uniformly on open disk D(0, 1/3)?
Σ (n/(n+1))z^n, start value n=1 to infinity.
I do understand that the series converges but what are the steps I need to do to know that it converges uniformly on open disk?

Comment: Then what? $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

For every $|z|\leqslant\frac13$ and every $n\geqslant0$,
$$\left|\sum_{k\geqslant n+1}\frac{k}{k+1}z^k\right|\leqslant\sum_{k\geqslant n+1}\left|z\right|^k=\left|z\right|^{n+1}\sum_{i\geqslant0}\left|z\right|^i=\frac{|z|^{n+1}}{1-|z|}\leqslant\frac1{2\cdot 3^n}.$$

Comment: can you please explain..

Comment: To quote Gaear Grimsrud from the movie "Fargo": [I did](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003303/quotes).